# Winforms GUI controls distribution

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, design-patterns, user-interface

I have a winforms tab control which has several tab pages. Within each tab page controls (textboxes, radio buttons, etc...) are group into groupboxes. These group boxes are arranged from top to bottom but in some occassions some groupboxes needs to be visible and other ones to be hidden. Also control within each group box sometimes (depending on the scenario) needs to be visible and sometimes hidden. So I would like to know if someone knows a good approach to do this, maybe some kind of pattern if any. Also it would be good to implement a generic solution to do this. Could any expert in GUI guide me in the right direction to do this?

Using C# and dot NET Framework 4.0, WinForms. This is a desktop application, not Web-based.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the scenarios in a class then add another class that will manage the layout by reading the scenario and laying the elements based on the scenario. I have not provided details because it varies on how specific you want to be and what behavior you want to achieve. It is better to put the Widgets inside a User Control and let that user control communicate with the layout manager.You can use the Mediator pattern or variation of it to coordinate between the widgets. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to group related controls into UserControls (even if this means doubling up on some controls) and adding them to or removing them from the form as needed. An example of this could be payment methods - when the user selects a specific payment method (Credit Card, Cash, Cheque, etc) a UserControl with the correct elements is displayed within a panel on the form.

A good pattern to use when managing this sort of set up is [Model-View-Presenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter), in the example, all the UserControls would probably implement an IPaymentMethod view interface and provide a way to update the corresponding models.